# Deploy vercel (Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGKILL)

Tags: deployment, vercel

I want to deploy my site on Vercel.
After 3 minutes of deployment, I have an error

Error

[image: 1]

Error deploy "npm run build"

[image: 2]

Comment: have you solved this problem? i am facing same problem in ubuntu 20

Comment: Yes, I have deployed from my terminal on VSC.
Here are the 2 commands to write
npm i -g vercel
vercel --prod
it should work

Comment: can you give any resources or explain again? it's important for me now

Comment: I am deploying my application to a VPS server. ubuntu-20 (version)

Comment: I'm talking about deploying a site on vercel not with a VPS

Comment: @YoannLABBE did you manage to resolve this? Facing similar problem. Perhaps you can share your package.json so we can compare dependencies? I'm running `next@12.1.4`.

Comment: @zkwsk - 
Yes, I have deployed from my terminal on VSC. Here are the 2 commands to write npm i -g vercel vercel --prod it should work